# bigquery group by all columns except a few

Tags: sql, group-by, google-bigquery

I have a table with loads of fields, and I am trying to group by all except two values which I am summing on. I would like to do something like

```
SELECT my_table.* except(value_1, value_2)
    , sum(value_1)
    , sum(value_2)
FROM my_table
GROUP BY my_table.* except(value_1, value_2)
```

But unfortunately `GROUP BY my_table.* except(value_1, value_2)` do not work. Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT DISTINCT * EXCEPT(value_1, value_2, grp),
  SUM(value_1) OVER(PARTITION BY grp) sum_value_1,
  SUM(value_2) OVER(PARTITION BY grp) sum_value_2
FROM (
  SELECT *, REGEXP_REPLACE(TO_JSON_STRING(t), r'"(?:value_1|value_2)":.+?[,}]', '') grp
  FROM `project.dataset.table` t
)
```

You can test, play with above using dummy data as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 value_1, 2 value_2, 3 value_3, 4 value_4 UNION ALL
  SELECT 11, 12, 3, 14 UNION ALL
  SELECT 21, 22, 3, 14
)
SELECT DISTINCT * EXCEPT(value_1, value_2, grp),
  SUM(value_1) OVER(PARTITION BY grp) sum_value_1,
  SUM(value_2) OVER(PARTITION BY grp) sum_value_2
FROM (
  SELECT *, REGEXP_REPLACE(TO_JSON_STRING(t), r'"(?:value_1|value_2)":.+?[,}]', '') grp
  FROM `project.dataset.table` t
)
```

with result as

```
Row value_3 value_4 sum_value_1 sum_value_2  
1   3       14      32          34   
2   3       4       1           2
```

Above will work with any number of columns and you don't need to reference them all explicitly - only those columns to be excluded to be explicitly referenced - value_1 and value_2 in this example

Comment: This is fantastic! Thanks a lot! Can you explain a little what this part is doing? 
`REGEXP_REPLACE(TO_JSON_STRING(t), r'"(?:value_1|value_2)":.+?[,}]', '') grp`

Comment: @FiercestJim - it convert whole row into json, then empties all values for value_1 and value_2 attributes so then you can use it as attribute for PARTITION BY

Comment: Are we sure that the order is always the same when serialising rows into JSONs? To me this looks risky since JSON is unordered by definition.

Comment: @Tonca TO_JSON_STRING returns a string in JSON format and does not 'create a JSON object' in a formal sense:

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json_functions#to_json_string